# How to substract string row wise in Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas

I like to subtract a string from another string in the same row.
in the example below, I like to remove oroville from "oroville 1974 honda st 90 very clean" and then create a new column with the remaining.

In fact I like to repeat the same for all rows and like to and up with "honda st 90 very clean" on the first row.
There is as usually False, NaN or zeros in the dataframe which may create problems.

I have the dict provided below.
Thank you for your help!

mydict={'brand': ['honda', 'yamaha', False, 'ktm ', 'yamaha'],'city': ['oroville', 'chico', 'chico', 'chico', 'red bluff'],'listing': ['oroville 1974 honda st 90 very clean','d/chico 2018 yamaha vino 50 classic','chico 2001 zrx1200r for sale','chico ktm 620 lc4', 'red bluff 2006 yamaha raptor 350'],'year': ['1974', '2018', '2001', 0, '2006']}

df=pd.DataFrame(mydict)

[image: dataframe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below uses just the method [Pandas.Series.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) adding the content to a new column:

```
df['new_column'] = df.listing.replace(df.city, '', regex = True).replace(df.year, '', regex = True)
```

With the following result:

[image]

Comment: This solution no longer work

Comment: Indeed, the replace method has changed. Adding '.values' after the column names must do the trick: df['new_column'] = df.listing.replace(df.city.values, '', regex = True).replace(df.year.values, '', regex = True)