# Subtract one text column from the other using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove the text that within one column from the other column vectorially. Meaning, without using loop or apply.
I found this solution that no longer works [old solution link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55211947/how-to-substract-string-row-wise-in-pandas).

Input:

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ABC', 'ABC'], 'B': ['A', 'B']})

     A  B
0   ABC A
1   ABC B
```

Desired output:

```
0    BC
1    AC
```

Comment: Do you have many times the same value in B? What is the output of `df['B'].value_counts()` in the real dataset?

Comment: yes, B values are very repetitive and sometimes they are within the corresponding value in A and sometimes they're not.

Comment: I made some tests, while you could use `df['C'] = df.groupby('B', group_keys=False)['A'].apply(lambda g: g.str.replace(g.name, ''))`, the list comprehension is still faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
df['C'] = [a.replace(b, '') for a,b in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]
```

Output:

```
     A  B   C
0  ABC  A  BC
1  ABC  B  AC
```

If you want a Series:

```
out = pd.Series([a.replace(b, '') for a,b in zip(df['A'], df['B'])], index=df.index)
```

Output:

```
0    BC
1    AC
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I want to avoid loops, and do it vectorially, that's why I asked not to use apply.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot do it in a vectorial way. A list comprehension will be faster than `apply`.

Comment: I have a question in another matter regarding using apply.
When does it faster to use a row wise apply (axis=1)?

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Yes for my first question, I could have use apply with substract, but it was much slower.
When should I use apply instead of using loops?

Comment: You should almost never use `apply` on `axis=1` for DataFrames. Use a list comprehension or python loop when you cannot vectorize. `apply` might be helpful for generating graphs, or things that don't have many iterations and require to have a Series during the iteration. I personally almost never used it.

Comment: Thanks, I just leaned something new :)